# leaflet map of the world - exclude Antarctica

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet

The code below is reproducible - it builds the map of the world using leaflet.
I am really not interested in Antarctica and I am more interested in Scandinavia :)
Any way to cut Antarctica or at least force it to be always at the bottom of the map - so that the center of the map is farther north?
Thanks a lot for any pointers!

```
library(leaflet)
library(rnaturalearth)
countries <- rnaturalearth::countries110
goodnames <- countries$name
goodnames[goodnames %in% goodnames[32]] <- "Ivory Coast"
countries$name[32] <- goodnames[32]
mymap <- leaflet(countries, options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 2))
myvalues <- 1:177
mycolors <- colorNumeric(palette = c("#fee6ce","#e6550d"),
                            domain = myvalues)(myvalues)
mymap %>%
 addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1,
             color = ~mycolors,
             label = countries$name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setView` to set the initial viewing point to any location of your choosing. If you want this map to focus on Scandinavia on opening, you can do...

```
mymap <- leaflet(countries, options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 2)) %>% setView(lng=18.6435,lat=60.1282,zoom=2)
```

The coordinates are simply from searching 'Sweden coordinates' on Google. You can use a site such as https://www.latlong.net/ to help you pick an appropriate center point.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately 'rnaturalearth' is not (yet) available fpr R 3.4.2 and I have just updated one second ago so I can't prove my answer. But as you're asking for any pointer -

I use the '[rworldmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rworldmap/index.html)' package and take out Antarctica by excluding it after the map is defined by the package.

According to this my suggestion to your code would be:

```
mymap <- mymap[-which(row.names(mymap)=='Antarctica'),]
```